# Typeahead to manage synonyms?

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

I recently stumpled upon typeahead/bloodhound, and tried to implement it on a page with local data. Got it all up and running, but have one question left.

Is it possible to implement some sort of static synonym list? I would like to handle examples like:

- Hospital <> Sygehus
- Cube <> Kube

Searching one or another should either search on both, or search if no result were returned on the first word. The list would probably not hold more than a handful words, so I'm thinking about manually updating the list.

But where/how could this be done? My setup is similar to the example for multiple datasets on typeahead.js ([typeahead example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/))

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution to my problem, yet probably not a pretty one. [Question about accents](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/271)

I found inspiration in this example and made two bloodhounds with normalization. One with `"Cube" : "Kube"` and one with `"Kube" : "Cube"`. Then I would get results for both Kube and Cube, instead of just Cube or Kube (using only one normalization).

```
      var charMap = {
        'a': /[àáâã]/gi,
        'c': /[ç]/gi,
        'e': /[èéêë]/gi,
        'i': /[ïí]/gi,
        'o': /[ôó]/gi,
        'oe': /[œ]/gi,
        'u': /[üú]/gi
    };

var normalize = function (str) {
    $.each(charMap, function (normalized, regex) {
        str = str.replace(regex, normalized);
    });
    return str;
};

var queryTokenizer = function (q) {
    var normalized = normalize(q);
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(normalized);
};

var foo_keywords = [
{name: 'foo1', keywords_query: normalize('foo1à, foo1ç, foo1ê'), keywords: 'foo1à, foo1ç, foo1ê', picture: '/img/foo1.png'},
{name: 'foo2', keywords_query: normalize('foo2à, foo2ç, foo2ê'), keywords: 'foo2à, foo2ç, foo2ê', picture: '/img/foo2.png'},
{name: 'foo3', keywords_query: normalize('foo3à, foo3ç, foo3ê'), keywords: 'foo3à, foo3ç, foo3ê', picture: '/img/foo3.png'}
];

var foo = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(normalize('keywords_query')),
  queryTokenizer: queryTokenizer,
  local: foo_keywords
});

foo.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead(
    {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'foo',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: foo.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            suggestion: function(el){return '<div style=\"display:table;\"><div style=\"display:table-cell;text-align:left;margin:0;width:100px;\"><img src="'+el.picture+'" style=\'width:100px;height:auto;\'/></div><div style=\"display:table-cell;text-align:left;margin:0;padding:10px;vertical-align:top;">'+el.name+'<br><font style=\"font-size:0.6em;color:#7b7b7b;\">'+el.keywords+'</font></div></div>'}
        }
    }
);
```

And then just using the two sources with ttAdapter().

Comment: Now my only problem is that the result will have duplicates for results not in the normalization list. hmmmm